# Spark JavaRDD get ten first values returned as JavaRDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have a JavaRDD

```
JavaRDD<Tweet> ordered = ... ;
```

As the name indicates, it has been ordered. I would like to take the top ten values (it's in descending order):

```
JavaRDD<Tweet> top10Followers = ordered.take(10);
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
incompatible types: java.util.List<Tweet> cannot be converted to org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD<Tweet>
```

take returns a list. Is there a way to get the top ten as a JavaRDD?

Comment: Any reason you are using a RDD instead of a Dataframe/Dataset? Can you share a little more code?

Comment: It is necessary in the given case... I guess my question is, is it possible to do this with an RDD (and not something else)?

Comment: I guess it is, maybe if you share a little more code...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my laptop to check so I will throw ideas. Sorry.

Since 10 is a small number, I would go with collect and then parallelize.. :-)

Assuming this is a more generic question than 10 but small enough to fit in a single partition then maybe:
 - repartition with 1  ( consider adding coalesce )
 - sort
 - zipWithindex
 - filter ( key smaller than "10"  )

IMHO zipWithindex will not do the job for multi partition (can't check) because it assigns indices first based on the partition index and then the ordering inside the partition.